# do we say "he is checking in to the building" to express someone is wiping his magnetic card on the security system to get in?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> [check in](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/check) [phrasal verb] 1  : to report to someone when you arrive
>   at a place (such as an airport or convention) to let them know you are
>   there
>
> Passengers must check in one hour before the flight leaves.
>
> Where do I have to check in?
>
> especially : to arrive at and be given a room in a hotel, motel, etc.
>
> check in [=register] at a hotel
>
> Guests cannot check in before 4:00 PM.

Some modern buildings or some security rooms are often equipped with some security systems. You need a magnetic card to get in, see this picture.

[image]

So, how do we express when someone is wiping his magnetic card on the security system to get in?

do we say "**he is checking in to the building**"?

The phrase "**check in**" in the dictionary doesn't seem to express the action of wiping the card to get into a building / room, etc.

Comment: "checking in to"

Comment: Colloquially I would probably say "he swiped into the building".  Note that swiping and wiping are different things.

Comment: @stevekeiretsu, "swipe" in this case is a transitive  verb right? so, do we say "swipe the card into the building"?

Comment: It is officially a transitive verb, and you're right, you are swiping the card; and yet, "swipe the card into the building" sounds to me like the main point is the card, rather than the person, getting into the building.  Which is why I phrased it like I did, but also why I noted that it was colloquial, because I suppose it doesn't make sense, strictly speaking.  Honestly, I'm not sure we have a single verb to refer to this, so you're left with slightly clumsy constructs like "he swiped his card to get into the building".

Comment: In my usage, and in particular in my large federal government workplace where identity and access cards are worn on lanyards around your neck, “swipe in” and “swipe” are definitely the verbs. “Check in” is never used in this way. I would not use “swipe *into* the building” (this strangely implies the building itself is checking your credentials) - but this is a possible way to say it in my usage. You swipe to *access* or *get into* a building.

Comment: Notice too that the verb is typically “swipe” despite the fact that the action is really more like a “tap”. Some older systems had a channel through which you did swipe your card and I suppose that is where “swipe” originates in this context.